# Java Delta encoding not working?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement this code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding
in java though it is not working. If i do it in C++ it works fine so i've been up late trying to solve this i don't have a club of what's wrong.

for example:

if i read a file.

input.txt

This is test for copy file.

it should write the encoded text in a file and it should also be able to read the encoded text and decoded on another file.

like this:

Normal Text:
This is a wonderful world.

Encoded Text:
T¶☺
¡I
⌠☼≈┤W°♥·°╩

Decoded Text:
This is a wonderful world.
Press any key to continue . . .

what am i doing wrong?

```
public static void delta_encode(String filename) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream reader = null;
    FileOutputStream  writer = null;

    try{
        reader = new FileInputStream (filename);
        writer = new FileOutputStream ("encode.txt");

        char last = 0;
        int c;
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1){
            char current = (char)c;

            writer.write(current - last);
            last = current;
        }

    }finally{
        if(reader != null)
            reader.close();

        if(writer != null)
            writer.close();
    }
}

    public static void delta_decode(String filename) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream reader = null;
    FileOutputStream  writer = null;

    try{
        reader = new FileInputStream (filename);
        writer = new FileOutputStream ("decode.txt");

        char last = 0;
        int c;
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1){
            char current = (char)c;

            writer.write(current + last);
            last = current;
        }


    }finally{
        if(reader != null)
            reader.close();

        if(writer != null)
            writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "it is not working" doesn't give us *any* indication of what's going wrong. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: "it is not working". That is very vague. What is the issue exactly? An error? The output is not what you expect? You need to provide more information.

Comment: the output is not what i expected.

Comment: i want something like this Normal Text:
This is a wonderful world.
Encoded Text:
T¶☺
¡I
⌠☼≈┤W°♥·°╩
Decoded Text:
This is a wonderful world.

Answer (score 0):

One core difference between C and Java is the encoding of the primitives.

Your mistake is assuming that Java `char` is the same as C's `char`. It isn't!

Try using `byte` instead of `char`.